# Passing complex structured data type from Lightning to Apex Controller causes Internal Error with Gack Id 263119078

Tags: lightning, error, platform-bug, gack

Passing complex structured data type from Lightning to Apex Controller causes 
Internal Error with Gack Id 263119078

[image: Internal Error with Gack Id 263119078]

```
    var action = component.get( "c.saveModel" );
    action.setParam( "model", component.get("v.model") );
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't even open a Salesforce ticket for this one, just observed that to avoid this Salesforce internal platform bug I can pass my model as JSON string

```
    var action = component.get( "c.saveModel" );
    action.setParam( "jsonModel", JSON.stringify( component.get("v.model") ) );
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {});
```

and to change my Apex Controller from

```
 public static Model saveModel( Model m ) {
     // perform some action with m
     return m;
 }
```

to

```
 public static Model saveModel( String jsonModel ) {
     Model m = (Model) JSON.deserialize( jsonModel, Model.class );
     // perform some action with m
     return m;
 }
```

Comment: Should your param `jsonPM` be `jsonModel` or does the name not matter? I had the same issue with a wrapper class.

Comment: Good point, Phil. When I was trying to generalize my code, I replaced my custom parameter only in one place, but I should have replace it in both places, I will update my answer